Getting Incidents for a Process in Camunda
Camunda 7 has GET /process-instance/{id}/activity-instances as per the documentation. The API can be used to fetch if a particular process has an incident. I do curious when will the parent incidentIds populated given I had this case where childActivityInstances has its incidentIds field populated but the parent incidentIds stays empty.
{
    "id": "0cf2bb40-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443",
    "parentActivityInstanceId": null,
    "activityId": "WF_PUBLISH_STUFFS:53:da73c566-7bb2-11ef-8168-a6f833f14b9d",
    "activityType": "processDefinition",
    "processInstanceId": "0cf2bb40-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443",
    "processDefinitionId": "WF_PUBLISH_STUFFS:53:da73c566-7bb2-11ef-8168-a6f833f14b9d",
    "childActivityInstances": [
        {
            "id": "ExtTask_GenerateDocument:0e1a98bf-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443",
            "parentActivityInstanceId": "0cf2bb40-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443",
            "activityId": "ExtTask_GenerateDocument",
            "activityType": "serviceTask",
            "processInstanceId": "0cf2bb40-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443",
            "processDefinitionId": "WF_PUBLISH_STUFFS:53:da73c566-7bb2-11ef-8168-a6f833f14b9d",
            "childActivityInstances": [],
            "childTransitionInstances": [],
            "executionIds": [
                "0e1a98be-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443"
            ],
            "activityName": "Generate Document",
            "incidentIds": [
                "7cbce466-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443"
            ],
            "incidents": [
                {
                    "id": "7cbce466-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443",
                    "activityId": "ExtTask_GenerateDocument"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Generate Document"
        }
    ],
    "childTransitionInstances": [],
    "executionIds": [
        "0cf2bb40-91ef-11ef-bc92-3ad8a98f2443"
    ],
    "activityName": "Publish Stuff",
    "incidentIds": [],
    "incidents": [],
    "name": "Publish Stuff"
}

Should I recursively checks for incidentIds to get all of incidents the process got? Is there another ways of getting incidents of a particular process as a list instead of having to navigate the json recursively?
Also, related question, if a service task activity had "technical error" (e.g. http request failed due to network issue) and it still has retries available, will it emit an incident?
Note: I'm running Camunda 7.16 to be specific

You can use the Incidents API to directly retrieve all incidents for a specific process instance: GET /incident?processInstanceId=<processInstanceId>
